# Get sequence of numbers in bash without using seq

Tags: bash, seq

I want to loop over a sequence of numbers in a BASH script, but the bound values are not constants. I know this syntax:

```
for year in {2000..2010}; do
  echo ${year}
done
```

But the values of 2000 and 2010 are changing in my case, so what I am doing right now is this:

```
for year in `seq ${yeari} ${yeare}`; do
  echo ${year}
done
```

Is there a bash-native way to do the same, without using `seq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `man bash`:

> ```
>  for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done
>           First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to
>           the rules described  below  under  ARITHMETIC  EVALUATION.   The
>           arithmetic  expression  expr2 is then evaluated repeatedly until
>           it evaluates to zero.  Each time expr2 evaluates to  a  non-zero
>           value,  list  is executed and the arithmetic expression expr3 is
>           evaluated.  If any expression is omitted, it behaves  as  if  it
>           evaluates to 1.  The return value is the exit status of the last
>           command in list that is executed, or false if any of the expres-
>           sions is invalid.
> ```

```
for ((i=yeari; i<yeare; i++))
do
  echo $i
done
```

You might possibly also be interested in 'Arithmetic Expansion' (`$((expression))`) of which you can find more in the man page.